# How to check string substring in Flask Html

Tags: python, flask

I am creating an app where I am reading a csv file and displaying the contents in then html page. When I am looping the cells and rows of the csv file I want to check if the cell contents is a url then I need to show as a URL.

My code `{% if cell in "http" %}` but the condition `cell in "http"` is not working. Can anyone guide me

If cell value is url then show as href.

Comment: Your check is the wrong way round

Answer (score 0):

You are checking in the wrong way.
To check if a string contains a substring, so if a substring is inside a string you should check if the substring is inside the string like this:

```
{% if substring in string %}
```

so in you case it would be

```
{% if "http" in cell %}
```

an even better way to accomplish what you are trying to achieve is to use regular expressions like this one for URLs:

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,65535}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cell in "http", try using if "http" in cell to check if the URL is present in the cell content.